# Programmatically open ShareLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

Using **ShareLink** shows a Share button so it opens Share popup when user taps on that button.

```
ShareLink(item: data, subject: Text("Subject"), message: Text("Message"))
```

I would like to programmatically screenshot and then share on share popup. Is there any way to perform action when user taps on ShareLink button or programmatically open SharePopup like we used to do in Swift as UIActivityController ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping a `UIActivityController` in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

In this example, I'm creating a `UIImage` on the click of a button, and then sharing it via `ImageWrapper` which is required as the `sheet` needs `item:` to be `Identifiable`:

```
struct ImageWrapper: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image: UIImage
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var imageWrapper: ImageWrapper?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // Use your UIImage here
            self.imageWrapper = ImageWrapper(image: UIImage())
        } label: {
            Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
        .sheet(item: $imageWrapper, onDismiss: {
            
        }, content: { image in
            ActivityViewController(imageWrapper: image)
        })
    }
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let imageWrapper: ImageWrapper
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageWrapper.image], applicationActivities: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Above logic works fine. I am unable to make UIImage as Identifiable with above code. Can you please guide me with that ?

Comment: No problem. I've updated the answer to work with a `UIImage`.

Comment: Cool. I had same thought but I thought there could be a better approach. Thanks.